# Getting shift/ctrl/alt states from a mouse event?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

In my `WPF` App, how do I get the state of the <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> keys in my mouse event handler? I seem to remember in `MFC` you could get that information from the mouse event.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that you're still in the mouse event handler, you can check the value of [Keyboard.Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx). I don't think that there is anyway to get modifier information from the event itself, so you have to interrogate the keyboard directly.

Comment: How annoying... if I understand correctly this means that if the user lets go of the keyboard between the time that the mouse event is fired and when the event handler interrogates the keyboard, it will detect the wrong key states.

Comment: @M.Dudley It doesn't matter whether you capture the keyboard state or WPF does ... the mouse and keyboard are disjoint, so the race condition is unavoidable.

Answer (score 19):

As per Andy's answer, you use Keyboard.Modifiers.  I figured I would post a little example

Something like this in your event handler should work:

```
private void MyExampleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Control is pressed");
    } else {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Control is NOT pressed");
    }
}
```

Regards,
Mike