# How can i check if ctrl,alt are pressed on left mouse click in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to check in my form if  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> are pressed on left mouse click. Is there any way of checking it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275371/getting-shift-ctrl-alt-states-from-a-mouse-event

Comment: It would depend on the type of application you are making. Is it a console app? A Windows Forms app? A WPF app? WinRT app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPF:
Add event to your window in xaml:

```
MouseLeftButtonDown="window_MouseLeftButtonDown_1"
```

or in code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.MouseLeftButtonDown += window_MouseLeftButtonDown_1;
}
```

and then you can check for the key presses in the call back

```
private void window_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt))
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
void window_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if more than one modifier keys are pressed, use **|** operator.

```
ModifierKeys.Equals(Keys.Control|Keys.Alt)
```

Or

```
Control.ModifierKeys==(Keys.Control|Keys.Alt)
```

This example show a message if both of ctrl and alt keys are pressed when mouse clicked:

```
if(ModifierKeys.Equals(Keys.Control|Keys.Alt)){
      MessageBox.Show("Ctrl&Alt keys were pressed sametime");
}
```